# Visual C++ (VS13) and MySQL connection with GUI (CLR)

Tags: c++, mysql, database-connection, visual-studio-2013

I need to make a "simple" c++ appliaction using Visual c++ that can connect to a database and get data from it and display it as either a text box or label.

I have dowloaded `boost` and the `C++ Connector` from mysql.com,
and included it to the project file like this:

The boost folder (boost_1_55_0) and the include dirictory of the connector in the Additional Dependancies in C/C++ General, and the Subsystem is Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS).

It fails to build, no matter what I try...

Here is the main.cpp:

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace sql;

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

void sqlfx() {
    Driver *driver;
    Connection *con;
    Statement *stmt;
    ResultSet *res;

    /* Create a connection */
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("localhost", "root", "");
    /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
    con->setSchema("test");

    stmt = con->createStatement();
    res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
    while (res->next()) {
        /*cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";*/
        /* Access column data by alias or column name */
        /*cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;*/
        /*cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";*/
        /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
        /*cout << res->getString(1) << endl;*/
    }
    delete res;
    delete stmt;
    delete con;

}

[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Project1::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Comment: Have you added the boost library to your include directories (Properties -> VC++ Directories) ?

Comment: @Blacktempel Yes indeed... Under the C/C++ > General > Additional Include directories > I have both, boost and the mysql connector.

Comment: Does it open the file correctly when you right click on the include -> "Open Document ..." ? Check this too.

Comment: @Blacktempel No it does not. But I don't know why... it is included as boost/variant.hpp and the parent folder is included, so there is a boost folder within that parent boost folder, so it should be working fine...

Comment: `#include <boost/variant.hpp>` Works fine for me, something must be wrong in your include settings.

Comment: @Blacktempel OK... Could you then please attach a screenshot of your additional dependencies dialog ?

Comment: http://i41.tinypic.com/294rton.jpg

Comment: He he, a CENSORED screenshot of include paths. Of unspecified project. Listen: more information might yield better and more to-the-point help.